# C++ bad_alloc caused by new?

Tags: c++, arrays, bad-alloc

[Fore note: I have read the existing threads in StackOverflow. None seemed to be on my question]

I am looking into the Quake 2 MD2 format. I seem to be getting a bad allocation after new'ing a pointer-array. However, if I do some horrible pointer manipulation, everything is fine.
I guess the question is, why am I getting such an exception?

The first "MD2Model::Load" works. The one I posted after it gets the exception.

Basic structures :

```
struct MD2Header
{
    int nIdentifier;
    int nVersion;

    int nSkinWidth;
    int nSkinHeight;
    int nFrameSize;

    int nNumSkins;
    int nNumVertices;
    int nNumUV;
    int nNumTriangles;
    int nNumCmds;
    int nNumFrames;

    int nOffsetSkins;
    int nOffsetUV;
    int nOffSetTriangles;
    int nOffsetFrames;
    int nOffsetCmds;
    int nOffsetEnd;
};

struct MD2Skin
{
    char szName[64];
};

struct MD2TexCoord
{
    short t;
    short u;
};

struct MD2Triangle
{
    short nVertex[3];
    short tu[3];
};

struct MD2Vertex
{
    float   fVertex[3];
    float   fNormal[3];
};

struct MD2Frame
{
    char szName[16];
    MD2Vertex* pVerts;
};
```

And now, the function that reads the .md2 file:

```
bool MD2Model::Load( const char* pszName )
{
    FILE* pFile = NULL;

    fopen_s( &pFile, pszName, "rb" );
    if( !pFile )
        return false;

    /* Read Header */
    fread( &m_Header, sizeof(MD2Header), 1, pFile );

    /* Allocate Pointers */
    m_pSkins = new MD2Skin[m_Header.nNumSkins];
    m_pTexCoords = new MD2TexCoord[m_Header.nNumUV];
    m_pTriangles = new MD2Triangle[m_Header.nNumTriangles];
    m_pFrames = new MD2Frame[m_Header.nNumFrames];

    /* Read Skins */
    fseek( pFile, m_Header.nOffsetSkins, SEEK_SET );
    fread( m_pSkins, sizeof(MD2Skin), m_Header.nNumSkins, pFile );

    /* Read Texture Coords */
    fseek( pFile, m_Header.nOffsetUV, SEEK_SET );
    fread( m_pTexCoords, sizeof(MD2TexCoord), m_Header.nNumUV, pFile );

    /* Read Faces */
    fseek( pFile, m_Header.nOffSetTriangles, SEEK_SET );
    fread( m_pTriangles, sizeof(MD2Triangle), m_Header.nNumTriangles, pFile );

    /* Read Animations */
    struct stMD2Vertex
    {
        unsigned char nVertex[3];
        unsigned char nLightNormalIndex;
    };
    struct stMD2Frame
    {
        float fScale[3];
        float fTranslate[3];
        char szName[16];
        stMD2Vertex verts[1];
    };

    unsigned char pBuffer[30000];
    stMD2Frame* pTmp = (stMD2Frame*) pBuffer;

    fseek( pFile, m_Header.nOffsetFrames, SEEK_SET );
    for( int i = 0; i < m_Header.nNumFrames; i++ )
    {
        fread( pTmp, 1, m_Header.nFrameSize, pFile );

        m_pFrames[i].pVerts = new MD2Vertex[m_Header.nNumVertices];
        strcpy_s( m_pFrames[i].szName, pTmp->szName );

        for( int j = 0; j < m_Header.nNumVertices; j++ )
        {
            m_pFrames[i].pVerts[j].fVertex[0] = pTmp->verts[j].nVertex[0] *
                pTmp->fScale[0] + pTmp->fTranslate[0];

            m_pFrames[i].pVerts[j].fVertex[2] = -1 * (pTmp->verts[j].nVertex[1] *
                pTmp->fScale[1] + pTmp->fTranslate[1]);

            m_pFrames[i].pVerts[j].fVertex[1] = pTmp->verts[j].nVertex[2] *
                pTmp->fScale[2] + pTmp->fTranslate[2];
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Variables dumped during debugging:

```
nNumSkins        1          int
nNumVertices     583        int
nNumUV           582        int
nNumTriangles    422        int
nNumFrames       1          int
```

(I ended up removing my D3DXVECTOR3 structures to see, so it's kinda fugly..)

Alright. So, inside the 'for' loop, is where it blows up.
If I were to do it like this:

```
//  unsigned char pBuffer[30000];
//  stMD2Frame* pTmp = (stMD2Frame*) pBuffer;

    fseek( pFile, m_Header.nOffsetFrames, SEEK_SET );
    for( int i = 0; i < m_Header.nNumFrames; i++ )
    {
        stMD2Frame* pTmp = new stMD2Frame();
        fread( pTmp, 1, m_Header.nFrameSize, pFile );

        m_pFrames[i].pVerts = new MD2Vertex[m_Header.nNumVertices];
        strcpy_s( m_pFrames[0].szName, pTmp->szName );
```

I get the bad_alloc exception during allocating the "m_pFrames[i].pVerts" statement.
Sometimes, I don't get it, but I do get the exception when I try to new my D3D class (I'm assuming I'll get it no matter what I new afterwards).
My MEM usage is extremely low, so could it be heap corruption?

I actually had to end up doing this during creating my VertexBuffer during animations as well.

Should I end up using vectors? I know they allocate more than needed, but it seems like the (most obvious)[best] way.

Comment: `bad_alloc` is typically thrown when you run out of memory. Try to monitor the memory usage of your program and `delete` the memory as soon as you don't need it anymore.

Comment: maybe you just overrun your pBuffer and write into the the loop count i and that just stops the loop from terminating.

Comment: Make i a global variable and see, if the behavior changes...

Comment: If `nNumVertices` is either negative or too large, you will get bad_alloc. Look at it in the debugger.

Comment: ``Andre, I should be allocating less than 50KB. ``Tortsen, I'm unsure of what you mean. The 'pBuffer' method works fine, even with 'large' models. ``n.m, no number is negative, I posted a code-snippet of the values.

Comment: what is the value of m_Header.nFrameSize? is it equal to sizeof(stMD2Frame)?

Answer (score 2):

I would check the line:

```
strcpy_s( m_pFrames[0].szName, pTmp->szName );
```

If the string loaded from the file is not null-terminated then this copy could end up overwriting your stack space and causing corruption.

EDIT

Looking again, I think the problem is that you define stMD2Frame as

```
struct stMD2Frame
{
    float fScale[3];
    float fTranslate[3];
    char szName[16];
    stMD2Vertex verts[1];
};
```

but this only has space for one vertex.

When you read in the frame as

```
fread( pTmp, 1, m_Header.nFrameSize, pFile );
```

you will corrupt your memory.

I suggest a check that

```
sizeof(stMD2Frame)>=m_Header.nFrameSize
```

before reading the data.

Comment: I triple checked that. The documentation says its null-terminated, as do the debugger. Also, the bad_alloc message comes before that, during allocating the m_pFrames[i].pVert.

Comment: you are great! I didn't catch that at all!
Now, just to tidy up my code, and get 15 rep points so I can up vote.